# Copy and email Etherpad content regularly

Tags: email, script, automation, webpage, to-do

I use [Piratapad](http://piratepad.net/front-page/) as a todo list for our printshop with 100+ members, and would like to once a month copy all active issues from the list and email it out to our members. What would be the simples way to go about this?

The page contains other things except what I'd like to email out, so most likely I'd have to use regex or somesuch to copy the relevant bits from the page. (marking it up with `TODOLISTSTARTSNOW` / `ENDSNOW` should suffice…)

I have a almost-always-on mac mini at home which could run this periodically, or perhaps I could have my webserver run it if my host allows.